# why this POW loop keeps the initial values?

Tags: c

I'm just starting to learn C. I wrote this beautiful little program that was meant to print "11111". But the pow function doesn't actualize the variable, that changes every time, that is being used in it.

I created the loop using if, goto and adding 1's. That's the only way I know to create a loop yet.

Can I overcome this problem using the same tools I've used?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main (void)
{
     int b = 0;
     int a = 0;
     int c = 0;

     up:
     b = pow (10,a);
     c = c + b;
     a = a + 1;

     if (a = 6)        
     {
         goto stop;     
     }
     else
     {
         goto up;
     }

     stop: 
     printf("%d\n",c);
 }
```

Comment: Even after indenting into a code block, your code has random blank lines, _very_ bizarre indentation, and is missing at least one line at the end. Please fix.

Comment: Why all the goto to implement a loop?  Why not something simpler, like `while (a=0;a<7;a++) { c += pow (10,a); }`

Comment: Have a look at `while` loops and try to restructure your code. The answer from Lightness Races in Orbit has identified the main cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (a = 6)
```

That sets `a` to `6`.

You probably meant:

```
if (a == 6)
```

Comment: @Robert: May not have warnings on. May not be using an IDE. May not be looking at the compilation output (wouldn't surprise me). May be ignoring it (also wouldn't surprise me).